# Mod_rewrite: Different behavior on different systems

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following .htaccess mod_rewrite rule:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(abc1|abc2|abc3|abc-defg)/([^/]+)$  /redirect/category/$1/$2
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])/$     /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Now I have the following url:

```
http://www.example.com/abc-defg/cat1/
```

which should be mapped to

```
http://www.example.com/redirect/category/abc-defg/cat1
```

This rule works on my local dev machine (Win7, Xampp), but not on production server (running Ubuntu 12.04 with Apache, mod_rewrite and mod_fcgid).

On Ubuntu, I get redirected to `http://www.example.com/abc-defg/cat1` (removed "/", which is the second rule).

How can I find out why it's not working as expected?

Comment: Ok, I will solve the redirect on php side (since it is only for "old" urls).

Answer (score 0):

You must place 301 redirect rule before first rule:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])/$ /$1 [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^(abc1|abc2|abc3|abc-defg)/([^/]+)$ /redirect/category/$1/$2 [L,NC]
```

Test this out in a new browser.

Comment: No, thats not the solution. The first rewrite is for old urls (we make a relaunch) and the second one is to prevent dublicate content. It doesn't matter, even if I comment out the seond one ('RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])/$ /$1') , it doesn't work as expected on Ubuntu.

Comment: Is `/abc-defg/cat1` a real directory on Ubuntu? First verify if this .htaccess is even read on Ubuntu by placing some random text in it and see if it generates 500 or not

Comment: As I said, this file is read and used, since the second regex is working.

Comment: There was 1 more question in my comment

Comment: What is the exact URL you enter in browser and what error do you get? (Examine in Chrome dev tool)

Answer (score 0):

Your regex doesn't match.

Try this:

`^(abc1|abc2|abc3|abc-defg)/([^/]+)/?$`

You need to clarify that it can end with a slash. Or alternatively (but not recommended), not end it with a slash.

`www.example.com/abc-defg/cat1` does match the regex - so I assume this is what you were using before.

That said it's entirely possible a user will put a slash at the end so it's best to account for it.

Comment: You are totally right! I don't know how it can work on my dev maschine, but the regex was wrong. But now, I can use the version with / and it works, but it doesn't work without a ending /, any ideas?

Comment: And the second weird thing is, if I use ^(abc1|abc2|abc3|abc-defg)/([^/]+)$, it doesn't work with /abc-defg/cat either :O

Comment: strange. the finishing ? should allow for a lack of / at the end. Testing in this site: http://martinmelin.se/rewrite-rule-tester/ shows it working.